# Cloudinary configuration is not read data from .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloudinary, dotenv

I'm using Cloudinary with my node.js project...

The issue is cloudinary.config is not reading data from .env file, I have to type them directly!

```js
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET,
});

cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
  file.tempFilePath,
  { folder: "test" },
  async(err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

I'll be thankful if anyone can help

Comment: You should normally add `require('dotenv').load();` at the top of your script to load the content of the .env file.

Comment: `.load()` gave me error, but I added `require("dotenv").config();` and it works. Thanks @LoicVdB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved with adding `require("dotenv").config();` to the beginning of the same file which contains **cloudinary.config**